# Non-static method requires a target when checking paramater for null values

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-4.5

In the below code, if i uncomment the line starting with `queItem.RequestedMap == null` I get

> Non-static method requires a target.

If I then instead rewrite it as it is now, with a `.ToList()` and then doing the same where query after that it works. This tells me that .net is not able to translate the null check of `queItem.RequestedMap == null` into something sql specific.

`queItem` is an object paramater passed to the method containing this code.

Is there a way I can write this without retrieving the data back to .net and then doing another where? The existing answers I found just said to remove such expressions from the lambda query, which I dont want to do.

```
var gameToJoin = db.Games
    //.Where(x =>
    //  (queItem.RequestedMap == null || x.Map.Id == queItem.RequestedMap.Id) // no map preference or same map
    //)
    .ToList()
    .Where(x =>
        queItem.RequestedMap == null 
        || x.Map.Id == queItem.RequestedMap.Id) // no map preference or same map)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Edit: Also, in the real query expression there are multiple other expressions in the first `.Where` that is commented here, they always need to be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var gameToJoin = db.Games.AsQueryable();
// add the where's that always need to be checked.
if (queItem.RequestMap != null)
{
    gameToJoin = gameToJoin.Where(x => x.Map.Id = queItem.RequestMap.Id);
}

var result = gameToJoin.ToList();
```

Or if you'd rather use FirstOrDefault()

```
var gameToJoin = db.Games.AsQueryable();
// add the where's that always need to be checked.
if (queItem.RequestMap != null)
{
    var result = new List<Game>();
    var game = gameToJoin.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Map.Id = queItem.RequestMap.Id);
    if (game != null)
    {
       result.Add(game);
    }
    return result;
}

return gameToJoin.ToList();
```

Comment: This would not be the same. If queItem.RequestedMap == null I want it to return the first match, I only want to do the check if it set to anything besides null i.e: if not null return the first item that matches with Map Id, if null then return anything.

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry about that, it should be fixed.

Comment: I would like to do it in one expression, but this might be as good as it gets. I'll probably do this for now.

Comment: It doesnt hit the db at least until you call tolist or firstordefault. So you can at least build your query before requesting the data

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this produce what you want? I don't see a reason that `queItem.RequestedMap` check should be a part the LINQ, because it is not a part the database.

```
Game gameToJoin = null;
if(queItem.RequestedMap == null)
{
     gameToJoin = db.Games
                    .Where(x => x.Map.Id == queItem.RequestedMap.Id)
                    .FirstOrDefault;
}
```

Comment: This is the right idea but the implementation isn't quite right... In the event that `queItem.RequestedMap == null` it shouldn't have the Where clause at all (since in the original the bit after the || wouldn't get evaluated if the first condition were true).

Comment: it would not be the same. If queItem.RequestedMap == null I want it to return the first match, I only want to do the check if it set to anything besides null i.e: if not null return the first item that matches with Map Id, if null then return anything.